# Unit Test are not failing

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine2.0

I am trying to write unit test cases, for web API call.

Which shows success below :

[Success Unit Test (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/g2Ntz/4/)

```
      getProduct("jsonp","https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/e
```

[Error Unit Test (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/g2Ntz/6/) But still its shows "pass"

```
       getProduct("jsonp","https://sdfsdfdfmaps.googleapis.com/maps/api/e
```

Previous right webapi url  : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536,-104.9847034&key

Wrong wepapi url : https://sdfsdfdfmaps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=39.7391536,-104.9847034&key

Even though the wepapi url is wrong. Test is passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spy function and add a `fail` callback which raises an error if the ajax call failed like so:

```
function getProduct(dataType,serviceURL,langCode ,callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: dataType,
        url: serviceURL + langCode,
        success: callback,
        fail: () => { throw new Error( 'failed' ); },
    });
}
```

See [this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g2Ntz/7/).

But this causes an actual call. To prevent the call from happening, use your spy function and parse the URL argument like [in this fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g2Ntz/8/).

Comment: thanks!! but not working for different service, where all i need to change to work the same for another service? i need to change anythignin base?